# How do I get MS-Access form entries to save to a table (or query)?

Tags: ms-access-2016

We have two teams working on system related issues and my Access database has one table for each teams open issues. I have created a query that matches issues from each list based on the system name. The query is returning potential matches correctly.

From there, I need to be able to review each "match" and select yes or no on a dropdown to confirm if both teams are working the same issue in order to quickly and easily reduce redundancies. I would prefer to review each result in a form format and have figured out how to add a dropdown box with the yes/no options; however, once I've validated each item, I'd like to filter the results down to only show the items that have been designated as "yes".

That's where I'm stuck. The form is not currently saving the results, including the dropdown info, to a table from what I can see.

How can I get the form to load to a table (or query) in order to filter out the "no" responses?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your query to an append query or an update query. Create a new table that this query adds data to, and in that table create a new field called "YesNo" or something like that. Put that new field from your table as a control source for your dropdown and should add a value in the "YesNo" field in your new table based on what you select. I'm not sure what value will be added to the table, I did something similar with a check box, when it's clicked it adds a "-1" and when it's unclicked, it adds a 0. Then I run a report that selects records based on the value in that field. I'm assuming the dropdown would work in a similar way but not a 100% sure. Hope I understood your issue, I'm no expert at access but I ran into the opposite issue recently where I didn't want the form to save the results.